# How to prevent cart price rules from applying to bundle products?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, bundled-product

I can't find a way to prevent cart price rules from applying to bundle products that already have a discount. The Bundle product has Dynamic Price = No.

I have tried to exclude items with a special price but this doesn't work - I assume because the rule is applying to the simple products that make up the bundle, and not the bundle itself?

Anyone found a way round this?